# Fluid simulation ignoring spring obstacle?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am currently working on a water slide simulation in Blender.

I created a spiral-shaped slide using the Spring modifier, and I have deleted the top half of the vertices on it (So so it would have sides blocking the water from getting out, otherwise it would just fall off)

Every time I try to bake the fluid, It just falls through the Spring. I have the spring set up as an obstacle, a cube as the inflow/fluid source, and I have set up the domain cube to cover the entire slide (and the cube).

[image]

Comment: Is your obstacle and fluid Outflow and Domain on the same layer? If not, place them on the same layer, then free bake, if you baked the water simulation and bake it again.

Comment: Have you applied the spring modifier before baking? Go back to the spring modifier, there should be an apply option. If that doesn't work, please upload your .BLEND to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can further assist you.

Comment: What is "Spring modifier" ? Maybe [it is Screw](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/how-to-create-a-bent-spring) ?