# Animating rocking horse with a spring base

Tags: animation

[image: e]

hello, I want to animate this rocking horse swinging back and forth (not up down)
I tried proportional editing and inserting keyframes
is there any modifier that i can use for more smooth transition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can be done with one spiral curve and a few modifiers, order is important

- add **Extra curve** (addon) > Spiral
- search **Convert to** Mesh
- deform by **Simple Deform** modifier > Bend
- add **Skin** modifier (after deform so spring is not squized/stretched)
- add Subdivision Surface modifier is needed to smooth shape

Animate **Deform Angle** in Simple Deform modifier properties. For nicer result you can use **Elastic** keyframe interpolation <kbd>T</kbd> on animation curve in Curve Editor.

[image]

[image]

For a bit more advanced spring shaping you can try also this [similar technique here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/how-to-create-a-bent-spring/2148#2148).

Or for easy animating things like spiral cabel I highly suggest Armature, generated by aawesome addon **Armature from Edge Loops**, that generates armature inside of spring (the link at first post to addon is working for me at Blender 3.x (located under *3D View > Properties > View > Bones from Mesh*)
Tutorial with blend can be found here
https://blenderartists.org/t/phone-cable-with-armature-in-3-min/520741

Comment: tyvm! you gave me so much useful information it's ganna take me many more hours to get the hang of it!