# How to simulate behaviour of the spring?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, screw-modifier

I have modeled a spring with SCREW modifier, placed it in a cylinder which is attached to the ground and I would like to run a simulation where the spring should compress when a cube fall on the spring. I would also like to know the behavior of the spring when a smaller cube fall on the spring.
[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piBb0rR1wgo -Hi there check this out

Comment: If you are going for realism I don't think that a cube of that size can compress a spring of that gauge(spring for is increases as gauge increases). The cube will simply compress the spring a little bit and it will fall off

Comment: if you search on this site "animate spring" there is a bunch of related. I remember one of mine https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166253/2214 with manually animated curve, but there are also rigged or physics solution, but it dipenc how your result should looks like to deside the effective solution.

Comment: hey @Nxdhin2005 thank you for the response. I am looking for the spring simulation(Realism), I do not want to control the spring compression and expansion in animation. I want to know its behavior. As you mentioned in your 2nd comment I will try reducing the gauge of the spring. It a very good input. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome i also found out that adding keframes to the scale on z axis can be used to some extend

Comment: You can learn how spring works from pixar itself . Found it a couple of days back . It is very useful It explains even the hooks law . Hope it helps you- You might also want to decrease the screw value since a normal screw with lower gauge will have very less space at the relaxed position HERE IS THE LINK-https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/pixar/simulation/hair-simulation-101/v/sim2-fix .     Courtesy-Khan Academy.