# Rigging/Animating this "EggOnSpring" isn't working how I want it to

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to make an animation of this egg and spring that makes it spin in a circle like a spring rider toy at a playground. I'm using automatic weights and when I try to move the armature bones it doesn't deform just how I want it to. I animated it with a curve to show what I'm trying to do but I need it done as a rig and don't know how to do that correctly.

[image]
[image]

Here is the blend exchange file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/32N5xKQx/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166253/2214

Comment: Can you use Bendy Bones that work only in Blender or do you need to export the armature? [How to Rig and Build an Advanced Bendy Spring in Blender](https://youtu.be/U0im90DN0-o)

Comment: For the spring armature there is a great addon [Armature from Mesh](https://blenderartists.org/t/armature-from-edge-loops/515611) (by Liero) ... still works under 3.4 (a bit weirdly located under *View 3D > Properties > View > Bones from Mesh > Create Armature*) Advantage of it is a mesh doess not deform thickness of wire.